# Jersey: org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc cannot be resolved

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I want to use Jersey MVC in my project.
I've never used Jersey MVC before.

I'm working in:

- Eclipse (Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1))

, using:

- Jersey 2.25.1
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.76.

---

Here's the example I'm trying to run:

**Hello.java**

[image]

**MyApp.java**

[image]

**NewFile.jsp**

[image]

I have downloaded jersey 2.25.1 from [here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html)

[image]

and added all jar files in

[image]

Here's how I call my web service:

[image]

---

The underlined import line tells:

[image]

So this is the problem I want to solve.

---

Because I have not found any information related to this problem I searched for jersey mvc related jar file. I found it [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-mvc/2.25.1/jersey-mvc-2.25.1.jar).

I added *jersey-mvc-2.25.1.jar* in *lib* folder.

So the package (and Viewable class) was found.

But when I run on server I get the following stack trace:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to add the jar file to your classpath/buildpath.

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: vote up for this question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

First of all,  *[jersey-mvc-2.25.1.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-mvc/2.25.1/jersey-mvc-2.25.1.jar)* is not enough to use MVC Jersey.

I downloaded the file [jersey-mvc-jsp-2.25.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-mvc-jsp/2.25/jersey-mvc-jsp-2.25.jar).

I put both jars in *lib*

[image]

---

Now here's my working basic example:

The structure of my project is:

[image]

The source code is:

**MyApp.java**

[image]

**Hello.java**
[image]

**NewFile.jsp**

[image]

To see the result I started the Tomcat server, then:

[image]

It worked!

---

Related to classpath/buildpath setting in Eclipse:

I didn't Add Jars (jersey-mvc-2.5.1.jar and  jersey-mvc-2.5.1.jar) in classpath or buildpath. It worked anyway.

---

What really helped to understand all this is:

[Absolute vs. Relative template reference](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/mvc.html#mvc.references)

[Annotations](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/mvc.html#d0e14897)

Answer (score 0):

This is a build path configuration Problem:

go to **BuildPath** ( Java Build Path) --> **Source**,

Change the test directory:

**Contains test sources**: --> *Yes*

**output folder**: a separate folder different from the main target folder.