# Jersey MVC: jsp issue: The requested resource is not available

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm working in:

- Eclipse (Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1))

, using:

- Jersey 2.25.1
- Jersey MVC
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.76.

---

Here's the structure of my application:

[image]

*Classes:*

[image]

*Jsp:*

[image]

I'm configuring my application by extending *ResourceConfig*:

**AppConfigs.java.**

[image]

Here's the resource class:

**ForumsController.java**

[image]

---

The problem is that I get *404-Not found* (for: http://localhost:8080/StudSiteProj/).

[image]

---

Can you, please, help me understand what's the cause?
I specified an absolute path in *return new Viewable(..)*, so I guess the application should search for *index.jsp* using this path. Why isn't this working then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

---

I found 2 problems:

### ***First problem***

***Cause:***

```
    The way @ApplicationPath annotation was written.
```

---

***Conclusion:***

It should not be like:

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

---

***Solution:***

So now my *AppConfigs* class is:

[image]

---

### ***Second problem***

***Cause:***

```
    JspMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH property was not set.
```

---

***Conclusion:***

I understood that this property might be what's missing by looking in apidocs [here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.8/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/jsp/JspMvcFeature.html#TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH). It said that:

[image]

So, if there isn't one, I have to set some.

---

***Solution:***

I set it to: */WEB-INF/app/views*

Now, my *AppConfigs* class looks like this:

[image]

The resource class *ForumsController* is now:

[image]

See, it's only:

[image]

, because the value in `JspMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH` will be prefixed to it. So "index.jsp" will be searched in:

[image]

This path is relative to servlet context path ( ex.: for my project, named *StudSiteProj*, the context path is */StudSiteProj*).

---

Here I worked with absolute paths (paths specified in Viewable).
But there exists another approach in Jersey MVC (relative paths).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500856/jersey-org-glassfish-jersey-server-mvc-cannot-be-resolved)'s my answer to my question =) on another stackoverflow page.